# Wired LAN and Localhost Setup in School

Tags: networking, server, 10.04, lamp, wired

In my school all 6 PCs ( ubuntu 10.04 desktop + LAMP + LAN Card ) + 5 NComputing Client in Single room Lab with one Router.

PC-1 ubuntu 10.04 32bit
Act as desktop + server + NComputing X-series X550 1kit
ref:http://www.ncomputing.com/products/xseries
image:http://www.ncomputing.com/files/images/diagrams/products_x550_6users-sm.jpg

PC-2 ubuntu 10.04 32bit
PC-3 ubuntu 10.04 32bit
PC-4 ubuntu 10.04 32bit
PC-5 ubuntu 10.04 32bit
PC-6 ubuntu 10.04 64bit

PC-7 NComputing Client (No CPU)
PC-8 NComputing Client (No CPU)
PC-9 NComputing Client (No CPU)
PC-10 NComputing Client (No CPU)
PC-11 NComputing Client (No CPU)

Query.1 I want to setup Wired LAN with static ip [start from PC-1].
Query.2 I want to setup LAMP server [PC-1 as server] with domain schoolname.
Query.3 All other PC [users] can access shared files, shared folders and http:// schoolname / from PC-1.
Query.4 All PC [users] can access shared internet using 3G Datacard on PC-1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some general observations :

1. Ubuntu 10.04 is end-of-line. You should upgrade to 12.04 LTS at a minimum.
2. NComputing clients use proprietary server software that AFAIK only runs on Microsoft operating systems.

Now for your questions. Basically, all you need is install Ubuntu server 12.04.3 LTS on your server (PC-1). It comes packed with everything you need. All you have to do is configure things.

For Q1, you might like to use DHCP configured to assign IPs based on client MAC Address, or avoid DHCP and just assign IPs manually on each client (not recommended if you plan to extend your network)

For Q2, you need to setup DNS and the LAMP stack that comes with 12.04

For Q3, just export the desired folders as NFS shares

For Q4, you need to configure PC-1 to act as a <del>router</del> gateway for your network.

For more information on how to set thing up, take a look at the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/index.html). You can even download it in pdf format from the same link.

*Edit in response to the comment:* Since you have decided to do this by yourself, there is no easy way or workaround for it. You have to **read and understand the documentation**, then (design and) implement according to your specific needs. Having said that, it's not terribly difficult if you have some basic knowledge on networks and you're not afraid to type commands in a console.

- How to install and configure Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol ([DHCP](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dhcp.html))
- How to install and configure Domain Name Service ([DNS](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/dns.html))
- How to install and configure LAMP stack (Linux Apache Mysql PHP)

  - [Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/web-servers.html)
  - [MySQL Database Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html)
  - Network File System ([NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html))

If you encounter any error or difficulty at any stage of the process, just take a look around the site. Chances are somebody else stumbled upon it before you. If you cannot find an answer, feel free to open a new question. Just don't forget to include any error messages that you encounter.

Comment: Thanks hmayag, I'm newbie to ubuntu or linux. Q1. assign IPs manually on each client. But how to?   Q2. setup DNS. But how to?  Q3. How to? Q4. How to?

Comment: In order for your vote to count you have to press the up arrow on the left of the answer. I appreciate it anyway.